# Increase DonutProgress/CircleProgress when pressing toggleButton?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to Android Studio and I have this project that is about tutorials. I am creating an app for tutorials and each tutorial has a toggleButton.
When the toggleButton is checked (true), the DonutProgress/CircleProgress, in the main menu of the app, should increase/increment its progress and the value in percentage that's inside the donut/circle and vice-versa (when unchecked(false) it will decrease/decrement.
What methods should I use and algorithm for the increase when toggleButton when checked(true)?

[image: Sample of DonutProgress/CircleProgress]

Comment: Try the answer below. Add following step by step

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add following stylable to `attrs.xml`

```
declare-styleable name="DonutProgress">
    <attr name="donut_progress" format="integer" />
    <attr name="donut_max" format="integer" />

    <attr name="donut_unfinished_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="donut_finished_color" format="color" />

    <attr name="donut_finished_stroke_width" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="donut_unfinished_stroke_width" format="dimension" />

    <attr name="donut_text_size" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="donut_text_color" format="color" />

    <attr name="donut_prefix_text" format="string" />
    <attr name="donut_suffix_text" format="string" />
    <attr name="donut_text" format="string" />

    <attr name="donut_background_color" format="color" />

    <attr name="donut_inner_bottom_text" format="string" />
    <attr name="donut_inner_bottom_text_size" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="donut_inner_bottom_text_color" format="color" />

    <attr name="donut_circle_starting_degree" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**2.** Add DonutProgress.java to your project

```
package com.app.components;

import java.util.Locale;

import com.app.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class CircularProgress extends RelativeLayout {

    private final Context context;
    private DonutProgress donutProgress;
    private TextView      progressPercent;
    private TextView      dataType;
    private boolean       isAnytimeData;

    public CircularProgress(Context context) {

        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        setUpComponent();
    }

    public CircularProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        setUpComponent();
    }

    public CircularProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        setUpComponent();
    }

    private void setUpComponent() {

        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_circular_progress, null);
        donutProgress =(DonutProgress) view.findViewById(R.id.donut);
        dataType =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data_type);
        progressPercent =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.progressPercent);
        TextView remaining =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remaining);
        dataType.setText(context.getString(R.string.title_not_available));
        addView(view);
    }

    public void setProgress(float progress) {

        if(progress == -1) {
            progressPercent.setText(context.getString(R.string.title_not_available));
            return;
        }

        donutProgress.setProgress(Math.round(progress));

        float result = progress -(int) progress;
        String percentSymbol = context.getString(R.string.percent_symbol);
        if(result == 0) {
            progressPercent.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d%s",(int) progress, percentSymbol));
        }
        else {
            String textValue = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.1f", progress);
            if(textValue.contains(".0")) {
                textValue = textValue.replace(".0", "");
            }
            progressPercent.setText(String.format("%s%s", textValue, percentSymbol));
        }

        if(isAnytimeData) {
            setDonutColor(progress, R.color.hughes_green);
            return;
        }
        setDonutColor(progress, R.color.hughes_blue);
    }

    private void setDonutColor(float progress, int progressColorId) {

        if(progress == 0) {
            donutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.circular_progress_red));
            donutProgress.setProgress(100);
            return;
        }
        if(progress > 0 && progress <= 10) {
            donutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.circular_progress_yellow));
            return;
        }
        if(progress > 10) {
            donutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, progressColorId));
        }

    }

    public void setDataType(CharSequence text) {

        dataType.setText(text);

    }

    public void hideDataType() {

        dataType.setVisibility(GONE);

    }

    public int getProgress() {

        return donutProgress.getProgress();
    }

    public void setAnytimeData(boolean anytimeData) {

        isAnytimeData = anytimeData;
    }
}
```

**3.** Add following to your layout file

```
<com.hughesnet.components.DonutProgress
    android:id="@+id/donut"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    custom:donut_background_color="@android:color/transparent"
    custom:donut_finished_color="#73B452"
    custom:donut_finished_stroke_width="5dp"
    custom:donut_unfinished_color="#A6A7A9"
    custom:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="1dp" />
```

**4.** Change progress

```
donutProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor (ContextCompat.getColor (context, R.color.circular_progress_red));
donutProgress.setProgress (100); //100 or any value
```

Comment: There are issues that I encountered:

1. Render errors when adding the attrs.xml

Comment: Disregard the first comment.
There are issue that I encountered:

1. Render errors when adding the attrs.xml